# What is the recommended way to modify the order of classpath entities when using Mule?

Tags: classpath, mule

What is the recommended way to have jars from my `$MULE_HOME/apps/app-name/lib/` directory take precedence over jars in `$MULE_HOME/lib/opt` directory?

MES 3.2.1's opt directory has mail-1.4.3.jar and I need mail-1.4.4.jar, the latter of which is in my application's lib directory. It appears, however, that the order in which these are loaded is inconsistent or fixed with Mule's libraries coming first.

I have hacked a solution by replacing mail-1.4.3 with mail-1.4.4 in `$MULE_HOME/lib/opt`, but would like a more robust way of doing this so I don't have to make the same change in all my Mule instances.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can embed your own JARs in your application's `lib` directory and use the `loader.override` property of the `mule-deploy.properties` deployment descriptor, documented [here](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Deployment+Descriptor).

If you want to learn more about classloading in Mule 3, turn to this [page](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Classloader+Control+in+Mule).

In your case, your deployment descriptor should look like:

```
loader.override=-javax.mail
```

Comment: Thank you David!  Unfortunately this doesn't appear to be an option for this library (at least in Mule Enterprise Studio 3.2.1) -- I get `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't override a system package. Offending value: javax.mail`

Comment: Gah! It's a system package :( No other choice than patching Mule IMO.

Comment: I meant 'Mule Enterprise Standalone 3.2.1', not 'Mule Enterprise Studio 3.2.1'

Comment: Thanks again for your help David.  I'll revert to the hack until I can get on a later version.

Comment: Based on Tomas B's recommendation from [this Mule forum post](http://forum.mulesoft.org/mulesoft/topics/what_is_the_recommended_way_to_change_modify_the_order_of_classpath_entities) I will not be juggling jars in `$MULE_HOME/lib/opt` but will be adding mail-1.4.4.jar to `$MULE_HOME/lib/user` as the latter is the directory intended for what I'm trying to do.